# Allowed to use “they’ve” in a new paragraph?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, paragraphs

Option A:

“Great! Your new account request has been sent to ABC company.

You'll be emailed a notification as soon as they've got your account ready for you to use.”

Option B:

“Great! Your new account request has been sent to ABC company.

You'll be emailed a notification as soon as ABC company has your account ready for you to use.”

Question:

Can I use “they’ve” or do I need to mention the name of the company so that paragraph 2 is “self-supporting”?

Comment: There is a distinct third party (you, 'they', and the communicator) demanded by (A) but only suggested by (B). But both seem to mix informal and formal registers awkwardly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer what I think are the underlying questions, clarified by 194 and Joachim in comments.

> **Antecedent Identification**
>
> The antecedent is the noun the pronoun represents in a sentence. When
> you see a pronoun, you should be able to understand its meaning by
> looking at the rest of the sentence. Look at the following sentence:
>
> The Smiths picked apples for hours, and they put them in large boxes.
>
> The antecedent for “they” is “the Smiths.” The antecedent for “them”
> is “apples.”
>
> ... ... ... ... ...
>
> As sentences become more complicated or whole paragraphs are involved,
> identifying pronoun antecedents might also become more complicated [(and remember that an antecedent is not obligatorily placed before the pronoun)]. As
> long as pronouns and antecedents are used properly, however, you
> should be able to find the antecedent for each pronoun.

[[Saylor.org](https://saylordotorg.github.io/text_handbook-for-writers/s19-06-connecting-pronouns-and-antece.html)]

And

> Don’t allow too much space between the pronoun and its antecedent. If
> you refer to Joe in the first sentence of a paragraph, and use him to
> refer to Joe throughout that paragraph, and Joe is the only male in
> that paragraph, there should be no problem. But if there are two males
> in the paragraph, or if you’ve written several sentences since you
> used Joe’s name, find a good place to use the noun again.

[[Kathy Ide](http://kathyide.com/pronouns-a-antecedents/)]

These guidelines are sound, echoing the Gricean maxim demanding clarity and ease of parsing (manner). Any prescriptive 'rule' barring antecedent-pronoun distribution across consecutive short paragraphs would be a broad-brush attempt to preserve clarity, and unnecessarily draconian in the simple extract in the question.

....................................................

> **How do you refer to a company in third person: it or they?**
>
> In English, both it and they are used to refer to a company....
>
> The choice depends on many things: context, type of written
> communication, house style, and more.
>
> The common view is that in American English, company is referred to as
> it, while in British English, company is referred to as it or they,
> but they is more common.
>
> In reality, many of those who write in American English use they to
> refer to a company. And many people who use British English call a
> company it. So there’s no drastic difference in usage on the two sides
> of the Atlantic....
>
> Whether you use it or they to refer to a company is a matter of style.
> If you choose it, you can’t go wrong. But they sounds more natural in
> many cases.

[[Christina N; Language Editing](https://www.languageediting.com/how-to-refer-to-a-company-it-or-they/)]

> If, throughout the [article], you refer to the company as a
> disembodied corporate entity (more distant and impersonal), it/its ...
> is probably preferred in your example.
>
> Conversely, if you consistently refer to the individuals that comprise
> the company, or its employees, or management team as knowable,
> discrete, personable entities, they/their seems more natural to me.
>
> Either would be considered grammatically correct.

[[T R Gritzmann; Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/grammar/comments/7jk14f/should_i_refer_to_a_company_as_it_of_they/)]

Answer (score 0):

Personal pronouns are used to replace nouns to avoid repetition.

Comment: And are allowed across separate paragraphs?

Comment: And is "they" the right pronoun for a company?

Comment: There is no reason to regard the second sentence as a 'new paragraph' just because you have chosen to write it on a new line. It follows on logically from the first sentence.

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks I kind of see what your saying. However, I thought by starting on a new line with a one line gap above makes it a new paragraph by definition. And as such grammatical rules associated with paragraphs apply? Unless I’m not aware of the definition of a paragraph?

Comment: In a long text, the writer usually starts a new paragraph to mark the transition to a new idea or incident. Your second sentence is simply the next stage in a series of instructions for setting up a new account, which you happen to be writing on separate lines for clarity. Personally, I would find it awkward to repeat the company's name every time it is mentioned. I would suggest using 'the company' rather than 'they'.